How to update AWS Pinpoint endpoint's OptOut attribute when user clicks on unsubscribe link?
I am using Amazon Pinpoint service to launch an email campaign to my users for marketing purpose and in my email message template I have used List-Unsubscribe and List-Unsubscribe-Post header to allow my user base for one click unsubscribe feature.
How can I generate a link that can be inserted in List-Unsubscribe header so that when a user click on Unsubscribe link in the email, the corresponding Pinpoint endpoint's optout attribute should be changed to ALL so that the user must not receive future marketing emails.
Is there a way to do this? In SendGrid there is a {{{unsubscribe}}} parameter that generates a link in the email and upon clicking it, the user's email address is inserted in the Global Unsubscribe list. How can we do the similar thing using Amazon Pinpoint Service without implementing any custom API or lambda function?
